# Marionette Collection Pagination

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have some issue with Marionette to set a pagination.

Here is my actual code :

```
  var Admin = Backbone.Model.extend();

  var AdminCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Admin,
    url: "/back/admin"
  });

  var RowView = Mn.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _.template(AdminRowView)
  });

  var TableView = Mn.CompositeView.extend({
    childView: RowView,
    childViewContainer: "tbody",
    collection: new AdminCollection(),
    template: _.template(AdminTableView),
    initialize: function() {
      this.collection.fetch();
    }
  });
```

The goal is to use slice() function on my collection.models and refresh my view with the sliced collection. (I prefer to manage the pagination client side)

How can I do this ?

Comment: Try to use [Backbone.Paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) or just review the source code.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this question?

Comment: I will try tomorrow, I will let you know, thanks you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a collection to your view on instantiation, Marionette handles collection resets for free (see [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/collection-view.js#L92)). To do so you should leverage the Promise `Backbone.Collection.fetch` returns. So for example when you're ready to instantiate `TableView`, do it like this:

```
var tableView; 
var pageQty = 10;
var options = {
  collection: new AdminCollection(),
  paginatedCollection: []
};

options.collection.fetch().then(_.bind(function () {
  // The collection is guaranteed to be filled
  // Set up your paginated collection
  for (var i = 0; i < options.collection.length; i += pageQty) {
    options.paginatedCollection[i/pageQty] = 
      options.collection.models.slice(i, i + pageQty);
  }
  // Load your first page
  options.collection.reset(options.paginatedCollection[0]);
  // Submit both the first page collection and your paginatedCollection
  // to the view
  tableView = new TableView(options);
  tableView.render() // Append the tableView.el wherever you want
}, this));
```

This view will render the first page of your collection on render. When you get a directive to change pages just do

```
this.collection.reset(this.options.paginatedCollection[newPageNumber]);
```

As you saw in the link to the source above, when you reset your view collection with the paginated models the view will remove the existing rows and render the new models.